# How to distinguish whether HTTPS decrypted on mitmproxy?

Tags: https, mitmproxy

I would like to inspect contents of HTTPS connection.
mitmproxy certificate has installed in root certificate store of client.

I have no idea how to distinguish whether decrypted correctly.

Following pictures are screenshots of mitmproxy that show response and detail.

Is this content decrypted or not?

#### Fig1:

[image: pic1]

#### Fig2:

[image: pic2]

Comment: Very simple: If you can see the request URL then HTTPS is decrypted.

Comment: If a request url (it's like https://example.com/foobar) is shown, is it means indicate decrypted correctly?

Comment: Yes. The advantage of HTTPS is that it decrypts everything, the whole HTTP request and the whole HTTP response inclusive the request URL, headers, ... So if you see one and it was an HTTPS request you can be sure that decryption works (at least partially for the specific application/library/whatever).

Comment: In my attached picture, Is payload data (The data exclude headers) is looks like decrypted?

Comment: Now for the third time, if you can read the URL, then it is decrypted, the URL/path is hidden by your red square after `GET`.